# Is it possible in theory to prove using a static analysis tool that Java code has no race conditions?

Tags: java, multithreading, theory, static-analysis, race-condition

Regardless of what static analysis tools available on the market, is it possible in theory to prove using a static analysis tool that Java (or any other imperative language) code has no race conditions?

Comment: You might consider asking this question at the new CS Stack Exchange site: cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think this will probably be Turing-complete.  I mean, in certain cases (all objects are immutable) it can be proved, but I would be shocked if it was doable outside of a few special cases.

Comment: Even if theoretically possible, it would still end up being unfeasible in practice, my guess. A hard problem.

Answer (score 4):

The statement "Java code has no race conditions" is pretty vague.  Maybe you mean one of these:

- Can a static analysis tool prove that no Java program has a race condition?  Clearly not, as there do exist Java programs with race conditions.
- Can a static analysis tool *always* prove that a race-condition-free Java program has no race condition?  No, because this is equivalent to solving the halting problem (put a static race condition after a loop which may or may not terminate.  To tell whether the race will actually happen, you need to know whether the loop terminates).
- Can a static analysis tool *sometimes* prove that a race-condition-free Java program has no race condition?  Yes.  In fact, such a tool would probably be very useful.

Comment: Does any such proof not diverge to proving that the OS underlying the JVM is also raceproof?  Good luck with that.  Windows source is proprietary and we already know that Linux has 'issues', eg. it supports the 'spurious wakeup' feature.

Comment: @Martin: sure, you have to assume that the JVM correctly executes the bytecode.  But just because the OS might have a bug does not negate the usefulness of proving that your Java code is race-free.

Answer (score 2):

This is just my intuition, but I'd say no, at least for Java programs in general. It shouldn't be too difficult to prove the absence of race conditions for *some* programs (trivially, any program that is single-threaded, and recognizing single-threadedness is not hard). But to make a decision for *all* Java programs? I suspect Java's concurrency model is too unrestricted for that.

I think it would be possible to prove that deciding absence of race conditions in arbitrary Java code is equivalent to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), given that some things (most obviously public static fields) are implicitly accessible to all threads, and that they can be accessed via reflection, with arbitrarily complex code determining the string used to look them up.

Comment: Proving the lack of a race condition is not itself equivalent to the halting problem. The issue with e.g. reflection is one of deriving the appropriate model, which might hit halting problem issues.

Comment: I don't understand... how is static analysis of a program for race conditions any different? Wouldn't the existence of a static analysis tool that can detect all race conditions imply that, for example, there are ways to determine if deadlock will occur (which itself results in the halting problem)? Also, shouldn't the non-determinism of race conditions somehow imply equivalence to the halting problem as well?

Comment: @AlexLockwood The halting problem does not relate to non-determinism of events; it does not deal with time at all. Analysing for deadlock also does not map onto the halting problem.

Comment: @Marcin: the above is not necessarily the most elegant or direct proof, just what occurred to me first: that analyzing for the presence of race condition requires detecting multithreaded access to fields, and when reflection is used that depends on the runtime value of strings, which can be computed by arbitrarily complex code, which is the halting problem.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Sure, but how much code involves complex calculation of strings to select fields through reflection, rather than selection between a closed set of strings?

Comment: @Marcin: yeah, but one example is all it takes to prove that it's not always possible.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Right, but the question isn't "Is there a universal model checker that can check all properties of all programmes". It reads much more like "Is it possible to check for race conditions in non-trivial non-contrived programmes".

Comment: @Marcin: I don't think you can draw a clear line between contrived and non-contrived here. There definitely are programs where it's possible, and programs where it's not possible, that much is certain.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using a modelchecker like spin (http://spinroot.com/spin/whatispin.html).

However, you would need to create the translation from java to the model language, and model checking of this sort is very computationally expensive (including eating up a lot of memory), so its viability is another question.

As noted in other answers, appropriate modelling may be difficult or impossible for especially convoluted code which obscures the actual calls made or data members accessed. However, for reasonable code, this should not actually be mathematically impossible (as opposed to really slow).

It would also be impossible to take account of any specific race conditions external to the code - so modelling something as an atomic IO operation which is not atomic would lead to an invalid model if there were a real risk of a race condition.

Comment: I think that if looked at closely, this definition of "reasonable code" will turn out to cover a very small subset of production code.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Really? How much production code involves higher order operations over an intractable set of properties/classes/methods?

Comment: many widely used frameworks do a lot of "magic" outside straightforward code exection, based on reflection, annotations and configuration files. Just think about Spring's dependency injection. Of course, they're actually designed to be maintainable rather than intractable, but IMO pretty much impossible to analyze generally, so your model would have to include all those frameworks' concepts.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Possibly for a global model. Not however if the intricacies of what it achieves boils down to something which can be modelled reasonably. On what do you base your opinion that e.g. Spring is incapable of modelling generally? Have you ever modelled it, or anything else, for the purposes of model checking or other formal methods? Or do you have a third-party proof?

Comment: sure, it could perhaps be modelled, but my point is that you'd have to model Spring, but I don't think you could model the mechanisms it uses (which includes parsing various XML files and annotations that can override each other) in a way that would have your model cover similar frameworks automatically. And at any point your could run into hidden complexity that, for special cases, is equivalent to the halting problem.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Given that the composite software artifact you are talking about includes XML, then either one would need to model spring after it had loaded all of the XML files, or rule your point out of order, as what is being modelled is no longer java code, but java + xml.